# How to test all ASP.NET Core Controllers Dependency Injection is valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automated-tests

We occasionally have issues whereby someone adds some DI into a controller but forgets to add the relevant line into Startup.cs to set the scope of the object.

This does not prevent the application from starting, but rather, throws an exception when the relevent endpoint is hit.

Is there any way of programmatically checking all controllers are valid and preventing the application from starting otherwise?

Alternatively is there an easy way to write a catch-all automated test to check every controller can be instantiated using the specified DI in Startup.cs?

Comment: You can write a unit test that finds all classes derived from *Controller* and then try and activate them via your DI mechanism.

Comment: Note that asp.net-core will now validate dependencies on startup by default.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I've just started an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and I'm not seeing this behaviour (I can hit endpoints with configured dependencies and still get 500 errors for endpoints without dependencies configured properly). Can you link where you saw this and how to configure it please?

Comment: There are limitations https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think its correct to say this is on 'by default' given all the ASP.NET Core templates don't have this enabled, so I think it needs calling out explicitly as to what needs adding to enable this. I have tried to summarise the (very long!) post in an answer below, although as you say, there are several caveats. Please let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Summarised from https://andrewlock.net/new-in-asp-net-core-3-service-provider-validation/, please see link for more details.*

As of ASP.NET 3.0 there is now a way to validate controller dependencies on build:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddControllersAsServices(); // This part adds Controllers to DI
```

Program.cs:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                // Validate DI on build
                options.ValidateOnBuild = true;
            });
```

Notes:

- Service provider validation is only enabled in the Development environment by default.
- Will not work for run-time ServiceProvider look ups (service locator pattern) e.g. `_service = provider.GetRequiredService<MyService>();`
- Will not work for `[FromServices]` parameters in methods (i.e. it only checks constructor dependencies)
- Will not work for 'open generics' e.g. `services.AddSingleton(typeof(MyServiceWithGeneric<>));`
- Will not work for services registered with factory functions e.g.

```
    services.AddSingleton<MyService>(provider => 
    {
        var nestedService = provider.GetRequiredService<MyNestedService>();
        return new MyService(nestedService);
    });
```

Comment: `AddControllersAsServices` bliss

Answer (score 8):

You can write it like this:

```
[TestFixture]
[Category(TestCategory.Integration)]
public class ControllersResolutionTest
{
    [Test]
    public void VerifyControllers()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<IntegrationTestsStartup>();
        var testServer = new TestServer(builder);
        var controllersAssembly = typeof(UsersController).Assembly;
        var controllers = controllersAssembly.ExportedTypes.Where(x => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(x));
        var activator = testServer.Host.Services.GetService<IControllerActivator>();
        var serviceProvider = testServer.Host.Services.GetService<IServiceProvider>();
        var errors = new Dictionary<Type, Exception>();
        foreach (var controllerType in controllers)
        {
            try
            {
                var actionContext = new ActionContext(
                    new DefaultHttpContext
                    {
                        RequestServices = serviceProvider
                    },
                    new RouteData(),
                    new ControllerActionDescriptor
                    {
                        ControllerTypeInfo = controllerType.GetTypeInfo()
                    });
                activator.Create(new ControllerContext(actionContext));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errors.Add(controllerType, e);
            }
        }

        if (errors.Any())
        {
            Assert.Fail(
                string.Join(
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    errors.Select(x => $"Failed to resolve controller {x.Key.Name} due to {x.Value.ToString()}")));
        }
    }
}
```

This code actually goes through full process of setting up asp.net core application with database configuration and what not you have in you startup so you might want to derive from it and remove/mock some stuff. Also this code requires [Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost/) nuget.

---

I changed original code that I posed as it was not working as expected.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately the test passes even when the controller has an interface in the constructor with no implementations. Does `GetService` definitely instantiate the controller using DI?

Comment: 2 things, unfortunately GetService returns null for objects it can't instantiate. I believe you meant `GetRequiredService`. Secondly, `GetRequiredService` doesnt work for controllers, as they are not registered and work differently to other objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: Fantastic answer! One small correction, please replace ```typeof(Controller)``` with ```typeof(ControllerBase)```

Answer (score 5):

Adapted [@Rafal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796196/608220) to xUnit to avoid managing Exception iteration and skip dependency on TestHost:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Xunit;

namespace redacted.WebApi.Test {
    using Core;

    public class VerifyDependencies {
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(Controllers))]
        public void VerifyController(Type controllerType) {
            var services = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>().Build().Services;
            ControllerUtilities.Create(
                controllerType,
                services.GetService<IControllerActivator>(),
                services.GetService<IServiceProvider>()
            );
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> Controllers() {
            return ControllerUtilities.GetControllers<ApiController>().Select(c => new object[] { c });
        }
    }

    public class ControllerUtilities {
        public static IEnumerable<Type> GetControllers<TProject>() {
            return typeof(TProject)
                .Assembly.ExportedTypes
                .Where(x => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(x));
        }

        public static Controller Create(Type controllerType, IControllerActivator activator, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
            return activator.Create(new ControllerContext(new ActionContext(
                new DefaultHttpContext {
                    RequestServices = serviceProvider
                },
                new RouteData(),
                new ControllerActionDescriptor {
                    ControllerTypeInfo = controllerType.GetTypeInfo()
                })
            )) as Controller;
        }

        public static TController Create<TController>(IControllerActivator activator, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) where TController : Controller {
            return Create(typeof(TController), activator, serviceProvider) as TController;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to throw `ArgumentNullException`s. For example, in your controller's constructor:

```
_foo = foo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(foo));
```

That will cause any action in the controller (any time the controller is constructed) to fail if the dependency is not satisified. Then, assuming you've got any sort of integration test suite around that controller, all your tests will instantly fail and you'll no exactly why: the constructor argument was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure [Rafal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495595/rafal)'s solution works, but I was unable to get it working. The `IControllerActivator` would not resolve, but I did end up figuring another way of doing this that does not require the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost library. You will, however, need [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/). Also, this is using MSTest.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ValidateDependencies()
{
    // This is only necessary if you have reliance on the configuration.
    // Make sure that your appsettings.json "Build Action" is "Content" and the "Copy to Output Directory" is "Copy if newer" or "Copy always"
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

    var svcCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    // We've moved our dependencies to an extension method
    svcCollection.RegisterServices(config);

    var controllers = typeof(CustomerController).Assembly.ExportedTypes
        .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(x)).ToList();

    // By default, the controllers are not loaded so this is necessary
    controllers.ForEach(c => svcCollection.AddTransient(c));

    var serviceProvider = svcCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var errors = new Dictionary<Type, Exception>();

    foreach (Type controllerType in controllers)
    {
        try
        {
            serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(controllerType);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(controllerType, ex);
        }
    }

    if (errors.Any())
        Assert.Fail(string.Join("\n",
            errors.Select(x => $"Failed to resolve controller {x.Key.Name} due to {x.Value}")));
}
```